# Create function to split delimited seperated data for all records in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2014

I have Input like this-

```
select ID,FIELD from TABLE

1| A,B,C,D
2|X,Y,Z
```

Output like this-

```
SELECT ID,FIELD from TABLE

1|A
1|B
1|C
1|D
2|X
2|Y
2|Z
```

Could someone please help me as how can I do it in SQL Server 2014 in an easy way ?

Comment: Tough luck, you have to clean up someone's bad choice to store data as comma separated items...

Comment: Btw, field is a very poor column name.

Comment: I used Field just as an example , the actual field doesnt have this name :)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a string splitting function from Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), and use it with [`cross apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to select the data from your table.
For this demonstration I've chosen to go with the XML string split function.
So first, create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Then all you need to do is something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Item
FROM TABLE
CROSS APPLY
dbo.SplitStrings_XML(FIELD, ',')
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/DVPK21692)

Also,you should probably read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Comment: Thanks for the effort buddy but it din't work . Not sure why

Comment: What do you mean bit din't work? Did you get an error? did you get wrong results? [I've tested your sample data on rextester](http://rextester.com/DVPK21692) and it seems to me it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should `XML` With `CROSS APPLY` no need Explicit `Function` :

```
SELECT ID,
       split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [FIELD]
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
           CAST('<M>'+REPLACE([Field], ',', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
    FROM #TM
) AS a
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS split(a);
```

**Result :**

```
ID FIELD
1  A
1  B
1  C
1  D
2  X
2  Y
2  Z
```