# horizontal to vertical in one field data - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-query-store

I have data in one field separated by comma "ID field
" and I need to write each number in one column vertically the data as below:

```
YEAR   WEEK BADGE   Name    remarks         BT_Hrs  NoOfDays    id
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1            36       4         440,824,104,412,741,900,000
```

the table needed as below

```
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1   36  4   440
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1   36  4   824
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1   36  4   104
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1   36  4   412
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1   36  4   741
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1   36  4   900
2017    1   1111    emp1    test1   36  4   000
```

Comment: Please show your expected output and the query you have tried.

Comment: @JINESHSHAH I have edited the question pls check.

Comment: i solve it thanks with XML and CROSS APPLY

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46772257/3623517